# Maven - Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm making a maven project in IntelliJ using Java SDK 13 with the following project tree:

```
bot.discord
    package1
    package2
    package3
    package4
    Bot.java
```

In my `pom.xml` file I have the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Discord Bot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!--Maven Compiler-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--Shade Plugin-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Discord JDA-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.3_464</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>club.minnced</groupId>
                    <artifactId>opus-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!--Discord JDA Utilities-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jagrosh</groupId>
            <artifactId>jda-utilities</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Lava Player-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sedmelluq</groupId>
            <artifactId>lavaplayer</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.34</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--SLF4J API-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--SLF4J NOP-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

That has worked for me before until that one moment when I tried to run the project and I got the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class bot.discord.Bot
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bot.discord.Bot
```

Why am I getting this error even though it has worked in the past?

---

I have tried to add the Maven JAR plugin and the Maven Assembly plugin I saw were helping people with the same problem but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

First change your artifactId to remove the space:

```
<artifactId>Discord-Bot</artifactId>
```

Your shade plugin should specify the main class as documented [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html)

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>bot.discord.Bot</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Then run from the jar

```
java -jar Discord-Bot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: I would suggest to use this as link: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html

Comment: run a mvn clean install from the command line, running it from Intelij is different

Comment: Just a `mvn clean package` is enough. `install` is not necessary.